# Showing that $\{(x,y):x-y\ne 2\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $A=\{(x,y):x-y\ne 2\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Would it be correct to argue that this set is open because for any $\vec{x}\in A$, we can pick $\varepsilon=\Vert \vec{x}-proj_{x-y=2}(\vec{x})\Vert >0$ so that $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\in A$. Thus $A$ is open.

I'm wondering if my definition of the $\varepsilon$ is correct, since $x-y=2$ does not go through the origin and is thus probably not a vector space. Alternatively, we could define this distance as $\frac{\lvert y_0-x_0-2\lvert}{\sqrt{2}}$, where $\vec{x}:=(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: Your answer does work, though there's a much easier way of approaching this: if you can express this set as $f^{-1}(U)$, where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is open and $f$ is continuous, you get the answer basically for free.

Comment: Not sure what $proj_{x-y=2}$ is supposed to stand for. You already said it yourself: $0 \notin A$, so $A$ can not be a vector space.

Comment: @user159517 I read it as meaning the orthogonal projection onto the line $x-y=2$, which seems to fit with the rest of the working.

Comment: @πr8: the orthogonal projection, as defined in linear algebra, in this case could possibly be interpreted as the projection of a vector onto a vector subspace, but neither $A$ nor the excluded line are vector spaces. Hence, I'm not so sure if what I wrote at all rigorous.

Comment: @πr8: actually, my mistake, $A$ appears to be a vector space.

Comment: $A$ isn't a vector space, as @user159517 says. I just mean projecting the point $x$ onto the point on the line which it's closest to.

Comment: Right, it's not closed under addition (had to refresh my memory about vector spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions already been answered, but I thought I would try one with just inequalities (and avoiding the messy calculations). Let $(x,y)\in A$. Then either $x-y>2$ or $x-y<2$. The cases are similar, so assume that $x-y>2$. Then there is a real number $r$ such that $x-y>r>2$. Define $\epsilon = \frac{r-2}{2} > 0$.

We will now show that $B_\epsilon(x,y)\subset A$. For $(x_1,y_1)\in B_\epsilon(x,y)$, we have $$x_1 - y_1 > (x-\epsilon) - (y+\epsilon) = x-y -2\epsilon > r-2\epsilon = 2.$$ So $x_1-y_1>2$ and $(x_1,y_1)\in A$. Therefore $B_\epsilon(x,y)\subset A$.

Checking the $x-y<2$ case is nearly identical. Thus $A$ is open.

Comment: Trevor: can you please explain why $x_1-y_1> (x-\epsilon)-(y+\epsilon)$?

Comment: If we imagine $x_1 = x + \delta_x$ and $y_1 = y +\delta_y$, then $|\delta_x|,|\delta_y| < \epsilon$. If we try to minimize $x_1 - y_1$ (that is, how close to zero can it be?) we would want to minimize $\delta_x$ and maximize $\delta_y$. With our bounds, $\delta_x>-\epsilon$ and $\delta_y<\epsilon$. This sets a fairly liberal lower bound for $x_1-y_1$, but the $\epsilon$ was chosen so that this is still greater than zero.

Comment: @sequence Try imagining a circle completely below the line $y=x-2$, and try to find the point $(x_{min},y_{min})$ in it such that $x_{min}-y_{min}$ is closest to zero.

Comment: Trevor: intuitively I understood your definition of epsilon, but I didn't get much from your explanation above. Why are $|\delta_x|$ and $|\delta_y| <\epsilon$? Also, why is $|\delta_x| <-\epsilon$, i.e. the negative of the epsilon? Other than that, I think, the picture is becoming clearer for me.

Comment: @sequence Suppose that $|\delta_x| \geq \epsilon$, i.e., that the x-coordinate of $x_1$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $x$. Then the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x,y)$ is at least $\epsilon$. Explicitly $\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2 + (y_1-y)^2} = \sqrt{\delta_x^2 + \delta_y^2} \geq \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \delta_y^2}  \geq \epsilon$

Comment: A circle centered around $(x,y)$ with radius $\epsilon$ can have a square drawn around it with sides of length $2\epsilon$. Obviously if a point is in the circle, then it is also in the square. This is what these inequalities means geometrically.

Comment: And I don't think I wrote $|\delta_x|<-\epsilon$. This is obviously not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\delta_x < -\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5):

Try with $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x-y-2$. Then $O:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f^{-1}(O)=A$.

Comment: And $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how this works. For example, $f(A)$ must be equal to $A$, but I don't see how. Also, if $f^{-1}(O)=A$, why does this imply that $A$ is open?

Comment: The continuous preimage of an open set is open - this is ([often?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces)) the definition of a continuous function in an arbitrary topological space.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

Here's another: $A$ is the complement of a set that's pretty easy to prove closed. That makes $A$ open.

(Your $A$ is a subset, but not a subspace, so the question is a little confusing.)

Comment: How would you prove that $A^c$ is closed? Would you argue that for any $x_0$ on the line $y-x=2$, there does not exist an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\in A^c$?

Comment: @sequence The limit of a sequence of values of $(x,y)$   which $x-y = 2$ satisfies that equality since the function $(x,y) \to x-y$ is continuous.